# How to horizontally print a list in subreport in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a two models Customer and Order as follow:

```
class Customer{
    private String customerName;
    private List<Order> orders; 
}

class Order{
     private String orderName;
}
```

I am creating a pdf that lists all the customer name vertically and its corresponding orders horizontally which look like below:

```
customer1                order1                     order2

customer2                order3                     order4
.
.
.
```

where `order1` and `order2` belong to `customer1` and `order3` and `order4` belong to `customer2`.

What I did is for each customer object, i will print the customer name and pass the orders list to another subreport and inside this subreport, i will print all of the element in this orders list but horizontally instead of vertically.

Here is my jrxml code:

***My main report:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="epicsReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="98e422a6-47f1-4bf1-9436-b6cbfdc8c904">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="ordersSubReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orders" class="java.util.List"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="270" height="25" uuid="26bf39b4-9072-4edc-a846-3141bff7da16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="8d2c2571-e603-4eba-8048-3053e3282a99"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="312" y="0" width="200" height="25" uuid="b2675578-87cc-4a7b-8b5a-2c8af0fbde73"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{orders})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{ordersSubReport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

***My subreport:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="skillsDataReport" columnCount="10" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="55" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c6d95fd0-d8af-4727-999c-9804a17721e4">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="orderName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="9" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="1ac7d520-9918-4106-b4ad-1b446da6a01f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

As data source for main report I pass a list of customers to it: `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{customers})`

And as data source for my subreport, for each customer object I pass a list of orders to it: `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{orders})`

The codes were compiled successfully but the orders list were not shown as I expected. I see only the list of customerName are printed but not the orders list.

What did I do wrong here? Any help will be a big glue for me :)

Comment: The concept seems correct, we would need a complete [mcve] to find what is wrong. Hence a complete (only relevant elements)  jrxml of both main and subreport. Also debug so that you orders list is not empty.

Comment: Hi Petter, I have updated my question with all the relevant info I think. And I am also pretty sure that the orders list is not empty because I have hardcoded the mock data for it

Comment: I don't won't sound lazy but I would like complete jrxml data of both reports (main and sub) containing only  relevant stuff, that I can copy and past and then check for things as what class is your $F{orders}, what band are your fields and subreport etc.

Comment: Hi Petter, I just updated the description :)

Comment: Your report [works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LKMYG.png) there is nothing wrong in your jrxml, either your mockup data is empty or you have an error that you are not posting (as not public Order class)

Comment: this seems strange here. Then I have to check it out again, thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: First check that your data is not empty, then use try catch and if you get any error please update your question with these including java code used to generate report